# pd.crosstab does not work after defining lists with categorical data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have 13 columns of categorical values, I defined them as lists, and trying to use pd.crosstab, however it returns an error

Columns look like:

```
A        B        C
A_good   A_late   A_person
B_good   A_late   B_person
C-good   C_late   A_person
A-good   B_late   B_person
```

I tried to create series or arrays, however it also returns an error.

## First I converted columns that are objects into categories:

```
obj_df =df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()
obj_df = obj_df.astype('category')
```

## After I defined x and y:

```
x = [[obj_df['a'], obj_df['b'], obj_df['c']]
y = [[obj_df['a'], obj_df['b'], obj_df['c']]
```

## And than I tried this:

```
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(x,y)
```

Instead of confusion matrix, I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-d554bd96c822> in <module>
----> 1 confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(x,y)
```

Comment: What is the size of x and y?

Comment: is `obj_df['a']` a series (column)?

Comment: it is categorical column with values such as :A_age, B_age, C_age

Comment: The size is 13 columns, 5000 entries in each. pretty small I think

Comment: what exactly is `obj_df['a']`? Can you print it out? Remember that `crosstab` only works if `x` and `y` are 1D arrays.

Comment: @QuangHoang - I edited the question, and added the way the columns look like. Data type for each one is 'category'

Comment: Given your sample data, try `pd.crosstab(obj_df['A'], obj_df['B'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the following. Surprisingly, pd.crosstab works great with objects, however if you convert object into category, it returns memory error.